# Setting up DLLs so we can update production ASP.NET app w/o full publish or app restart

Tags: asp.net, dll

We have DLLs that contain hundreds of custom client processes that are kicked off from an ASP.NET application.  Our clients run these processes while performing data entry, and typically there's only 1 process per client.  On any given day, we might update 2 or 3 of these processes.

Currently these are all housed in a series of DLLs, which means that we are publishing our application a couple times per day.  As a result, any logged-in clients get booted out of the system since the publish causes an app restart.

Is there a way that we can update these DLLs without requiring a full publish each time?

Comment: If they are in the bin directory, then no

Answer (score 2):

If your client processes have a common API then you could host, the DLLs separately in a WCF (or similar) service, and call the client processes remotely. So basically, consider moving to a service oriented architecture.

Answer (score 1):

You can switch to SQL server or state server sessions in order to perserve session and logged users after app restart. Or store these dlls in APP_DATA and load it dinamically. Then of course you have to think of some refreshing system and refresh loaded dlls with newly uploaded ones.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Managed Extensibility Framework (MEF)](http://mef.codeplex.com/) from Microsoft. It provides not only dependency management but also plug-in like library loading. Most likely it's exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: MEF alone will not help with loading DLLs as they change.

Answer (score 0):

There is no *sensible* way to avoid an application restart. Please note the emphasis on the word sensible.